# Laravel Asgard CMS Menu with Custom Classes

Tags: php, laravel-5, presenter

I'm using Asgard CMS in one of my prjects.

I'm trying to print a menu with custom classes.

By defaut, `{{ Menu::get('main') }}` prints out the main menu with Bootstrap classes. But, I want to use different classes because of my theme.

In their documentation, they say that by creating a `Presenter`you can do this. However, when I create a Presenter named `CustomPresenter.php` with a class named `CustomPresenter` that extends `Pingpong/menus/Presenters/Presenter.php`, place it under `/vendor/xxx/` and calling it by `{{ Menu::render('main', 'XXX/CustomPresenter') }}`in my blade, Laravel gives **Class 'XXX\CustomPresenter' not found** error.

Here is the code I use in CustomPresenter:

```
namespace XXX;

use Pingpong\Menus\Presenters\Presenter;

class CustomPresenter extends Presenter
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getOpenTagWrapper()
    {
        return  PHP_EOL . '<section class="top-bar-section">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getCloseTagWrapper()
    {
        return  PHP_EOL . '</section>' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getMenuWithoutDropdownWrapper($item)
    {
        return '<li'.$this->getActiveState($item).'><a href="'. $item->getUrl() .'">'.$item->getIcon().' '.$item->title.'</a></li>';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getActiveState($item)
    {
        return \Request::is($item->getRequest()) ? ' class="active"' : null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getDividerWrapper()
    {
        return '<li class="divider"></li>';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc }
     */
    public function getMenuWithDropDownWrapper($item)
    {
        return '<li>
                <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                 '.$item->getIcon().' '.$item->title.'
                </a>
                <ul style="display: none;">
                  '.$this->getChildMenuItems($item).'
                </ul>
              </li>' . PHP_EOL;
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://asgardcms.com/docs/menu-module/displaying-menus):

> To register this new presenter you need to add it to the package configuration (`config/packages/pingpong/menus/config.php`)

Did you do that?

```
return array(
    'navbar'        =>  'Pingpong\Menus\Presenters\Bootstrap\NavbarPresenter',
    'navbar-right'  =>  'Pingpong\Menus\Presenters\Bootstrap\NavbarRightPresenter',
    'nav-pills'     =>  'Pingpong\Menus\Presenters\Bootstrap\NavPillsPresenter',
    'nav-tab'       =>  'Pingpong\Menus\Presenters\Bootstrap\NavTabPresenter',
    'zurb-top-bar'  =>  'ZurbTopBarPresenter',
);
```

Also documentation does not mention to place your class in `vendor/xxx` directory. Main rules of using composer is to not editing `vendor` directory manually. You should place your class in your app folder using your app namespace (directory `App\Http\Presenters` would be best).

Comment: Yup, no luck. It's old by the way, the file locations are not the ones indicated above.

Comment: @yenerunver Move your file from `vendor` directory to `app` directory and change namespace to `App\XXX\CustomPresenter`.

Comment: i have made it work by moving my presenter under App\Http\Presenters and making necessary changes. If you can edit your answer, i can give the bounty to you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to dump-autoload via composer

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to autoload the namespaces, depending on the package you might have to do

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

if it does have any configuration files that you need to create prior to using the render method.

Good Luck

Comment: above answer solved my question, so didn't try your way, which probably would work too. Thanks.

Comment: glad it worked for you, Good luck with future development @yenerunver